# What is a "reunion special"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I came cross this phrase in the sentence below.

> ‘teen mom 2’ reunion special had some surprising plot twists spoilers.

I assume it might mean an interview or something?

Answer (score 3):

Typing that into [youtube search](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=teen+mom+2+reunion+special) should show you some video clips of it since that is a TV show.

A reunion is a gathering of people to the same place to meet up again and converse and hopefully have fun.

Most common reunions would be like family reunions where aunts and uncles and cousins that may or may not see each other much since they could live in different areas, all meet up in one location and spend time together.

Another common reunion is high school reunions where the class of a specific year gets together after like 10 years, 25 years, 50 years, from when they graduated high school.

So basically a reunion is just a meeting of people that have something in common, like blood or went to the same high school.

All the different teen mom's had something in common in that they were all on the same TV show. So after that season of the TV show ended, they have a reunion where they talk about that previous time.

A "special" in this context is just a special program. Not a regular episode of Teen Mom.